# Qt - requiring new model rows to be non-empty

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, signals-slots

I'm making a program where the user can add multiple people (participants) in a list. When the "Add" button is clicked, a new row is added and "edit" is called for the name field. All is well so far, but there is a thing I'd like to implement, and I can't seem to figure out how: when the user closes the editing field (presses enter or escape, clicks elsewhere, etc.) and if the name field remains empty, I'd like the row to be deleted. In other words, a name has to be filled in. Here is what I have so far:

```
void MainWindow::addParticipant()
{
    QList<QStandardItem *> newRow;
    newRow << new QStandardItem()
           << new QStandardItem();
    participantModel->appendRow(newRow);
    participantView->edit(participantModel->index(participantModel->rowCount()-1, 0));
}
```

Here `participantModel` is a `QStandardItemModel` and `participantView` is a `QTreeView`. I tried using signals and slots to detect when a row is empty and to delete it, but it hasn't worked and the syntax is elusive to me.

Ideally I'd be able to detect when the name field is not being edited anymore, so that I can delete the row if need be.

Comment: Presumably the code that attempts to validate the row data has access to the `QStandardItem`s that you would want to remove.  That being the case can't you use the standard `QStandardItem` members `parent`, `row` and `removeRow` to achieve your goal.  Difficult to judge without seeing more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments/answers posted thus far have urged me to look more into item delegates. Quite embarrassingly, after relatively little googling I found the following solution for my problem:

```
void MainWindow::addParticipant()
{
    QStyledItemDelegate *participantDelegate = new QStyledItemDelegate;
    participantView->setItemDelegateForColumn(0, participantDelegate);    
    QList<QStandardItem *> newRow;
    newRow << new QStandardItem()
           << new QStandardItem();
    participantModel->appendRow(newRow);
    connect(participantDelegate, SIGNAL(closeEditor(QWidget*,QAbstractItemDelegate::EndEditHint)), this, SLOT(checkRow()));
    participantView->edit(participantModel->index(participantModel->rowCount()-1, 0));
}
```

Apparently the `closeEditor` signal (only available to delegates) is exactly what I was looking for. When the editor is closed, the slot `checkRow()` checks if the name field of the participant is empty and decides whether or not to delete the row.

Answer (score 0):

Here is ugly but working solution: subclass from `QItemDelegate` and check input data inside `setModelData` member function. As far `setModelData` has a `const` qualifier you can not modify model inside it, so you need some trick: in the following example the model is modified inside handler of `closeEditor` signal.

```
class MainWidget : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWidget ()
    {
        QStandardItemModel * model = new QStandardItemModel ();
        ItemDelegate * delegate = new ItemDelegate ();
        table->setItemDelegate (delegate);

        connect (delegate, & ItemDelegate::closeEditor, [=](){
            if (isEmpty) {
                model->removeRow (emptyRow);
                isEmpty  = false;
                emptyRow = -1;
            }
        });

        connect (delegate, & ItemDelegate::cellEdited, [=](const int row){
            isEmpty  = true;
            emptyRow = row;
        });
    }

    bool  isEmpty;
    int   emptyRow;
};

class ItemDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void cellEdited (int) const;
public:
    void setModelData (QWidget * widget, QAbstractItemModel * model, const QModelIndex & index) const override
    {
        if (0 == index.column () ) {
            if (QLineEdit * cellWidget = qobject_cast <QLineEdit *> (widget) ) {
                if (cellWidget->text ().isEmpty () ) {
                    emit cellEdited (index.row () );
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        QItemDelegate::setModelData (widget, model, index);
    }
};
```

Complete example available at [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/Gluttton/SOS/tree/master/38411579).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's not the solution I ultimately used, but it motivated me to look more into item delegates and it really helped me find my own solution.